# Sqlite cannot find class when creating table

Tags: c#, android, sql, class, xamarin

I have two classes, `Event` and `ScoutData`

```
public class Event
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public Event()
    {
    }
    public Event(string start, string end, string name, int id, bool isCurrent)
    {
        startDate = start;
        endDate = end;
        eventName = name;
        ID = id;
        isCurrentEvent = isCurrent;
    }

    public string startDate
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string endDate
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string eventName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public bool isCurrentEvent
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class ScoutData
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }   

    public ScoutData()
    {
    }

    // Some public properties, including a public Event from the other class
}
```

When I try to add tables to the sqlite connection

```
public EventDatabase()
{            
    _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
    _connection.CreateTable<ScoutData>();
    _connection.CreateTable<Event>();
}
```

The `Event` table generates fine, but the `ScoutData` table throws this exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about App6.Event

Class `ScoutData` uses `Event` inside of it, but everything is public. I've tried renaming, cleaning, etc but can't seem to figure out why sqlite will create tables for some classes but not others.

Comment: SQLite.NET only handles primitive .NET types.  What you're trying to do is essentially create a FK relation between two tables.  There is a separate SQLite Extensions packages that enables you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a table `ScoutDataEvent` or so, to get a connection between the two tables.

```
public class ScoutDataEvent
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public int ScoutDataID { get; set; }
}
```

With this Table you can delete your public Event in the ScoutData-Table and call the Event-Table with the ScoutDataID. For Example :

```
var sD = conn.Table<ScoutData>().FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
var sDE = conn.Table<ScoutDataEvent>().Where(p => p.ScoutDataID == sD.ID).FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
var event = conn.Table<Event>().Where(p => p.ID == sDE.EventID).FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Jason said, if you use [SQLite.Net Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/) you can do it like so :

```cs
public class Event
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

// Need the foreign key here
    [ForeignKey(typeof(ScoutData))]
    public int ScoutDataId { get; set; }

    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string endDate { get; set; }
    public string eventName { get; set; }
    public bool isCurrentEvent { get; set; }

    public Event()
    {
    }

    public Event(string start, string end, string name, int id, bool isCurrent)
    {
        startDate = start;
        endDate = end;
        eventName = name;
        ID = id;
        isCurrentEvent = isCurrent;
    }
}

public class ScoutData
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; } 

// I don't know what relationship you are looking for but this is one to one:
    [OneToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public Event Event { get; set; }  

    public ScoutData()
    {
    }

    // Some public properties, including a public Event from the other class
}
```

Also if you are using async then use the async version [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions.Async/)